# swap data from t1 table to t2 table and t2 table to t1 table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
T1                T2    
id  name        id  name
1   a           1   e
2   b           2   f
3   c           3   g
4   d           4   h
```

output:-

```
    T1               T2 
    id  name        id  name
    1   e           1   a
    2   f           2   b
    3   g           3   c
    4   h           4   d
```

Comment: What about just rename the tables

Comment: Do you really expect an answer? This is not even a proper question...

Comment: Maybe you can share the context of why the swap is necessary, as well as asking a proper question? To be fair, if there is no compelling reason for permanently swapping anything, then you can simply change your queries to pull data from T1 instead of T2, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Don't swap values From T1 to T2, because if records are in large then it will take more time to swap the data just rename tables as Follows

```
EXEC sp_rename 'T1', 'T1_10' 
EXEC sp_rename 'T2', 'T1' 
EXEC sp_rename 'T1_10', 'T2'
```

You can find documentation on this procedure on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

If you need to include a schema name, this can only be included in the first parameter (that is, this cannot be used to move a table from one schema to another). So, for example, this is valid:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'myschema.T1', 'T1_10'
```

**Update :**

As OP Table structure Here Id Also need to be rename

```
sp_rename [PK_tblKeyTEST] ,[PK_tblKey]
```

Thanks To @[TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243373/tt) for pointing

Comment: Works good, note though that any dependent names (constraints, indexes, PK names etc) will not be renamed. Can make for some awkwardness if the table name is encoded in those dependent names.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy t1 to a temporary table

   ```
   SELECT * INTO #swap FROM t1;
   ```
2. Empty t1

   ```
   DELETE FROM t1;
   ```
3. Copy t2 to t1

   ```
   INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM t2;
   ```
4. Empty t2

   ```
   DELETE FROM t2;
   ```
5. Copy temporary table to t2

   ```
   INSERT INTO t2 SELECT * FROM #swap;
   ```

To account for any mistakes wrap this in a transaction to be sure. So in all:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    SELECT * INTO #swap FROM t1;
    DELETE FROM t1;
    INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM t2;
    DELETE FROM t2;
    INSERT INTO t2 SELECT * FROM #swap;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    PRINT 'Success';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    PRINT 'Fail';
END CATCH
```

Comment: Seems overly burdensome when it's possible to just rename a table.

Comment: @MatBailie True. Personally, I'm not too hot on renaming tables... Not that it always matters, but all associated names remain the same (index names, constraint names, ...) and they will not be renamed. Can be awkward in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve the above by doing `Inner Join`:

```
select t2.* from t1
inner join t2 on t2.id = t1.id ----- T1

select t1.* from t1
inner join t2 on t2.id = t1.id ----- T2
```

Result :

```
T1              T2 
id  name        id  name
1   e           1   a
2   f           2   b
3   g           3   c
4   h           4   d
```